# Angular 6 setting up a directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

It seems I can't make directives work in my application. I am not getting any errors and when I reproduce in stackblitz it works fine.  I was [having this problem a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522512/angular-6-directive-is-not-being-instantiated-in-app-but-is-in-proof-of-concept) when I first tried to implement this directive but I hesitated saying that it was actually a problem in my application with 'custom directives' themselves... no one ended up answering this question. Now I come to you with more information.

Please let me know. **Do you see anything wrong with my setup?  What am I missing?** I feel I have tried everything.

Here's what I have tried:

Works in Stackblitz: I know how to make [a directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/save-horizontalscrolldirective-static-decoupleddom).

But THIS very simple directive doesn't work in my app (please find code at bottom) (clarification: doesn't work = I do not see the console.log or the attribute that the shadow directive is supposed to apply)...
Template:
[image]
Directive:
[image]
Module:
[image]
I have tried declaring it in the closest module like above, but I have also tried in app.module. In addition I have tried importing through a dedicated module (i don't think I needed the export but it shouldn't hurt).
Dedicated Module:
[image]

Template:

```
<!-- <div #windowsnap class="blade-container" (mouseup)="BladeSnappiness()" (mousedown)="CloseSidebar()"> -->
<div #windowsnap class="blade-container" windowsnap>
  <!-- level 1 -->
  <org-management-blade *ngIf="level1 === 'orgBlade'"> </org-management-blade>
  <org-profile *ngIf="level1 === 'orgProfile'"> </org-profile>

  <!-- level 2 -->
  <org-setup *ngIf="level2 === 'orgSetup'"></org-setup>


  <!-- level 3 -->
  <org-create-admin *ngIf="level4 === 'orgCreateAdmin'"></org-create-admin>
  <org-new-security-profile *ngIf="level4 === 'newSecProfile'"></org-new-security-profile>
  <org-railroad-filter *ngIf="level4 === 'newSecRailroadFilter'"></org-railroad-filter>

  <!-- level 4 -->
  <org-security-permissions *ngIf="level5 === 'newSecPerms'"></org-security-permissions>

  <!-- level 5 -->

</div>
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[windowsnap]' })
export class ShadowDirective {
    constructor(elem: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
        renderer.setStyle(elem.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') CloseSidebar() {
        console.log('windowsnap directive');
    }
}
```

Module:

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrolltocomponentModule,
    MaskedTextBoxAllModule,
    AgGridModule,
    // ShadowModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    OrgManagementComponent,
    OrgManagementBladeComponent,
    OrgSetupComponent,
    OrgInfoComponent,
    OrgAdminsComponent,
    OrgSecurityProfilesComponent,
    OrgRailroadFilterComponent,
    OrgSecurityPermissionsComponent,
    OrgNewSecurityProfileComponent,
    OrgCustMappingComponent,
    OrgCreateAdminComponent,
    OrgProfileComponent,
    ShadowDirective
  ]
})
export class OrgManagementModule { }
```

Dedicated Module:

```
import { ShadowDirective } from './shadow.directive';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ShadowDirective
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    exports: [
        ShadowDirective
    ]
})
export class ShadowModule { }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": *omitted*,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "babel-watch server.js",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/elements": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.1",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "1.3.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-ng-inputs": "^16.2.53",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^18.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^18.1.1",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.6.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "syncfusion-javascript": "^16.3.22",
    "touch": "^3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.1",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "msal": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-packagr": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tsickle": ">=0.25.5",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

stackblitz package.json

```
@angular/common5.0.0
@angular/compiler5.0.0
@angular/core5.0.0
@angular/forms5.0.0
@angular/platform-browser5.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic5.0.0
@angular/router5.0.0
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap1.0.0
core-js2.5.1
rxjs5.5.2
zone.js
```

Comment: could you provide the relevant parts of package.json ? could be related to versions of angular/related tools you are using . (and check difference with the versions in your StackBlitz)

Comment: added package.json!  Checking stackblitz now

Comment: I'm sorry but your directive is applied to selector `[appShadow]` while you are not using this property name anywhere in your template. Try to change the selector or just use it?

Comment: I put the wrong code there, sorry Im updating it

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty easy to debug to know if the Directive is active or not.

Use bracket in directive in html. Change this

```
<div #windowsnap class="blade-container" windowsnap>
```

to

```
<div #windowsnap class="blade-container" [windowsnap]>
```

If `Directive` is not registered correctly, `Angular` will throw the error

> windowsnap is unknown property..

If you get this error, just declare the `Directive` to closest `Module`.

Comment: Again, I'm not getting any errors.  I am not seeing the console log within the directive either though...  Thanks for your suggestion.